# changing class with onkeypress

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning javascript and i'm using bootstrap so i don't really have to worry about css.
I have a form group and i want to add class as the user inputs something. Here's my code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="loginForm">
    <label for="inputLogin" class="pull-left">Login</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLogin" placeholder="Enter login" onkeypress="changeToGreenBorder('loginForm','inputLogin')">
</div>
```

and it's calling those functions:

```
function changeToGreenBorder(string,string2){
        var tag = getElement(string);
        var tag2 = getElement(string2);
        if (tag2.innerHTML.length > 6) {
            tag.setAttribute('class','form-group has-success');
        } else if({
            tag.setAttribute('class','form-group has-error');
        }
    }

function getElement(string){
        var doc = document;
        return doc.getElementById(string);
    }
```

It's working with the error class, but when it has more then 6 letters, it doesn't switch to success class. How can i solve this?

Comment: `} else if({` notice that lingering `(` is that supposed to be there?

Comment: i fixed this but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Check the Answer I just gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a lingering `(` and a `Else If` without a condition so I'm thinking you don't need a `Else If`
You were also trying to get the lenght of the `innerHTML` when what you really wanted was the `length`of the elements' `value`;

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zbke65b/1/)